# How to send POST request from React to Flask without submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

Hey sorry I'm completely new to React and Javascript and I'm really confused about this. I'm trying to create a section where I will have a dropdown list in React. I have already fetched the data from Flask and now when I click my chosen option, I want to send the POST request to Flask (without clicking any submit button).

I was reading different answers and trying to figure it out so I used "fetch" while getting the data and "axios" when trying to send the request.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { DropdownItem } from "../Components/DropdownItem"
import Select from "react-select"
import axios from "axios"

export const DropdownPage = () => {
    const [years, setYears] = useState([])
    const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setYears(data)
            })
    }, [])

    const handleDropdownSelectYear = (e) => {
        setSelectedYear(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleDropdownSubmitYear = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e)
        axios
            .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/yearselect", selectedYear)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form method="post" onSubmit={handleDropdownSubmitYear}>
                <select onChange={handleDropdownSelectYear}>
                    <option value="">Select Year</option>
                    {years.map((year) => (
                        <DropdownItem key={year.id} year={year}></DropdownItem>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**api.py**

```
class Year(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} {self.content}'


def year_serializer(year):
    return {'id': year.id,
            'content': year.content}


@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return jsonify([*map(year_serializer, Year.query.all())])


@app.route('/api/yearselect', methods=['POST'])
def yearselect():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        year = Year(content=request_data['content'])
        db.session.add(year)
        db.session.commit()
        return {"201": request_data['content']}
```

If there's any other information/code you need, please let me know. Also, I'm planning to recreate this image below. So, when I make my selection on the first dropdown, it should send a request to flask and narrow down the options for the next dropdown and so on. Let me know if you need any clarification. Thanks!!
[image]

Comment: When do you want to send the POST request? When a value from the dropdown is selected?

Comment: As shown in the picture, when you select a year (say, 2021), that selection will be used to find which Grand Prixs happened in 2021 and React will fetch that data from Flask. Wouldn't I need a POST request to achieve this?
I'm completely new to these concepts so sorry if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the POST request when a selection is made, you don't need a `<form>` or a submit handler.

Instead, add an effect hook that listens for changes to `selectedYear`

```js
// if selectedYear is going to be an object, don't initialise it as a string
const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedYear) {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/yearselect", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(selectedYear),
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) return Promise.reject(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        // do something with data ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }
}, [selectedYear]); // effect hook dependencies
```

Effect hooks also run when the value is initialised so checking the value of `selectedYear` before making the request is advisable.

---

The Axios equivalent would be

```js
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/yearselect", selectedYear)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    // do something with data
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.toJSON());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try it please .. You can send data to backend onchange functıon directly called `handleDropdownSelectYear` function

```
const handleDropdownSelectYear = (e) => {
    setSelectedYear(e.target.value)

    console.log(e)
    axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/yearselect", e.target.value)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

or you can use useeffect .

```
const handleDropdownSelectYear = (e) => {
    setSelectedYear(e.target.value)
}
useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedYear) {
        axios
            .post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/yearselect", selectedYear)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
  }
}, [selectedYear]);
```